# Selenium java AbstractWebDriverEventListener tracking events don't fire

Tags: java, selenium, events

I'm writing a automation with selenium and it is required to track everything, I found the **AbstractWebDriverEventListener** with **EventFiringWebDriver** sample, followed the manual but the events don't fire. There is some working example to see or something wrong below ?

```
//+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
package fooautoweb;
import foowebtools.EFooBrowserType;
import foowebtools.FooBrowser;
public class FooAutoWeb {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        FooBrowser bw = FooBrowser.getInstance(EFooBrowserType.FIREFOX);
        if(bw.gotoUrl("https://www.google.com/ncr")){
            System.out.println("equal!");
        }
        System.out.println(bw.getCurrentUrl());
        bw.close();
        bw = null;
    }
}
//+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

.

```
//+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
package foowebtools;
public enum EFooBrowserType {
    FIREFOX 
}
//+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

.

```
//+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
package foowebtools;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.events.AbstractWebDriverEventListener;
public class FooBrowserListener extends AbstractWebDriverEventListener {
    //-------------------------------------------------
    @Override
    public void beforeNavigateTo(String url, WebDriver driver) { System.out.println("Before navigating to: '" + url + "'"); }
    //-------------------------------------------------
    @Override
    public void afterNavigateTo(String url, WebDriver driver) { System.out.println("Navigated to:'" + url + "'"); }
    //-------------------------------------------------
    @Override
    public void beforeChangeValueOf(WebElement element, WebDriver driver) {
        String msg = "Value of the:" + element.toString() + " before any changes made"
        System.out.println(msg);
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------
    @Override
    public void afterChangeValueOf(WebElement element, WebDriver driver) { System.out.println("Element value changed to: " + element.toString());}
    //-------------------------------------------------
    @Override
    public void beforeClickOn(WebElement element, WebDriver driver) { System.out.println("Trying to click on: " + element.toString()); }
    //-------------------------------------------------
    @Override
    public void afterClickOn(WebElement element, WebDriver driver) { System.out.println("Clicked on: " + element.toString()); }
    //-------------------------------------------------
    @Override
    public void beforeNavigateBack(WebDriver driver) { System.out.println("Navigating back to previous page"); }
    //-------------------------------------------------
    @Override
    public void afterNavigateBack(WebDriver driver) { System.out.println("Navigated back to previous page"); }
    //-------------------------------------------------
    @Override
    public void beforeNavigateForward(WebDriver driver) { System.out.println("Navigating forward to next page"); }
    //-------------------------------------------------
    @Override
    public void afterNavigateForward(WebDriver driver) { System.out.println("Navigated forward to next page"); }
    //-------------------------------------------------
    @Override
    public void onException(Throwable error, WebDriver driver) { System.out.println("Exception occured: " + error); }
    //-------------------------------------------------
    @Override
    public void beforeFindBy(By by, WebElement element, WebDriver driver) { System.out.println("Trying to find Element By : " + by.toString()); }
    //-------------------------------------------------
    @Override
    public void afterFindBy(By by, WebElement element, WebDriver driver) { System.out.println("Found Element By : " + by.toString()); }
    //-------------------------------------------------
    @Override
    public void beforeScript(String script, WebDriver driver) { /* non overridden methods of WebListener class */   }
    //-------------------------------------------------
    @Override
    public void afterScript(String script, WebDriver driver) { /* non overridden methods of WebListener class */ }
    //-------------------------------------------------
}
//+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

.

```
//+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
package foowebtools;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver;
public class FooBrowser implements AutoCloseable {
    //-------------------------------------------------
    private WebDriver _browser;
    private FooBrowserListener _bevtlistener;
    private EventFiringWebDriver _bevtfirer;
    //-------------------------------------------------
    public static FooBrowser getInstance(EFooBrowserType eFooBrowserType) {
        FooBrowser bwi = new FooBrowser();
        bwi._browser = new FirefoxDriver();
        bwi._bevtfirer = new EventFiringWebDriver(bwi._browser);
        bwi._bevtlistener = new FooBrowserListener();
        bwi._bevtfirer.register(bwi._bevtlistener);
        return bwi;
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------
    public boolean gotoUrl(String url) {
        boolean reached;
        this._browser.get(url);
        reached = (url.equals(this.getCurrentUrl()));
        return reached;
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------
    public String getCurrentUrl() {
        return this._browser.getCurrentUrl();
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------
    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception {
        if (this._browser != null) {
            this._browser.close();
            this._browser = null;
        }
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------
}
//+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the **this._bevtfirer** instead of **this._browser** on **this._browser.get(url);** line and events get fired. Just use **this._bevtfirer.get(url);**